# Foo - No Globals | Remove identifier if no return

Tags: javascript

```
/********************************************************************************************
 * ToDo - Make CIO and IServer basic functions....complete break down to functions. 
 *******************************************************************************************/
/********************************************************************************************
 * foo.js - Module / File / Element Tracker
 ********************************************************************************************

 * Model
                | mSession
 * View
                | vTPane
                | vBPane
                | vFlipP
 * Control
                | cServer
                | cIO
                | cTryIt        | tryit_button
                | cBlocks       | bottom_left_link, bottom_right_link
                | cSignIn       | signin_email_input, signin_email_label,signin_pass_input, signin_pass_label, 
                                | signin_button
                | cSignUp       | signup_name_input, signup_name_label, signup_email_input, signup_email_label, 
                                | signup_pass_input, signup_pass_label
 * Independents
                | iSerialize
                | iFont 
                | iStyle

 ********************************************************************************************
 *******************************************************************************************/
( function ( window, document ) 
{
"use strict";
/********************************************************************************************
 ********************************************************************************************
 *Modle
 ********************************************************************************************
 *******************************************************************************************/
function mUserTry()
{
    cServer( 'model=user_try',function( response_text )
    {
        var array = JSON.parse( response_text.substring(3) );
        mSession( 1, 'Test Account', 0, 0, 'Main' );
        vStateElements( 'Test Account', '0' ); 
        vBPane( array[1] ); 
        vTPane( array[2] );
        vFlipP( 'page_main' );
    } );
}
function mUserNew()
{
    cServer( 'model=user_new',function( response_text )
    {
        var array = JSON.parse( response_text.substring(3) );
        mSession( array[0], 'Test Account', 0, 0, 'Main' );
        vBPane( array[1] ); 
        vTPane( array[2] );
        vFlipP( 'page_main' );
    } );
}
..

....

......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arc` in your code is undefined. The whole Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IFFE) returns nothing to `Arc`.

Assuming that your code does nothing at all via the `Arc` reference and it's just being used as an initializer, we can simplify the code:

```
//the Arc reference was useless since the IFFE returned nothing
//in the end, this whole IFFE basically just prevents global pollution
//as well as executing the code immediately

(function (window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    //move these references outside the constructor
    //these elements are static. calling the functions call document.getElementById
    //to reference them again and again is an overhead when in fact, they don't change
    var tryit_button = document.getElementById('tryit_button'),
        bottom_left_link = document.getElementById('bottom_left_link'),
        bottom_right_link = document.getElementById('bottom_right_link'),
        signin_button = document.getElementById('signin_button'),
        signup_button = document.getElementById('signup_button'),
        signup_pass_input = document.getElementById('signup_pass_input');

    //use a function declaration (normal function) rather than a function expression (function in variable)
    //this gives you the advantage of "hoisting" - functions are moved up and exist before
    //operations even when they are declared after operations in the code
    function Cin() {
        function cTryIt() {
            tryit_button.addEventListener("click", function () {}, false);
        }

        function cBlocks() {
            bottom_left_link.addEventListener("click", function () {}, false);
            bottom_right_link.addEventListener("click", function () {}, false);
        }

        function cSignIn() {
            vStyleTwitter(["signin_email_input", "signin_email_label", "signin_pass_input", "signin_pass_label"]);
            signin_pass_input.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {}, false);
            signin_button.addEventListener("click", function () {}, false);
        }

        function cSignUp() {
            vStyleTwitter(["signup_name_input", "signup_name_label", "signup_pass_input", "signup_pass_label", "signup_email_input", "signup_email_label"]);
            signup_pass_input.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {}, false);
            signup_button.addEventListener("click", function () {}, false);
        }

        this.initPage = function (page) {
            if (page === 'splash') {
                cTryIt();
                cBlocks();
                cSignIn();
                cSignUp();
            }
        };
    };

    //operations:
    console.log('ArcJ.js is Active');
    new Cin().initPage('splash')
}(this, document));
//use "this" instead of window. some developers say it's safer than using window
//pass in document as well
//Doug crockford recommends the parameter list be in the expression parenthesis
```

Comment: @stack.user.0 no, they don't persist through page changes. but in your original code, every call to functions like `cTryIt` and the rest calls `document.getElementById` which is an overhead. you can reference the element once in an outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

The singleton pattern `(function(x){...})(bar)` is useful for performing some complex set of actions once, without putting a bunch of members in the global namespace (or some other scope), and/or allowing the argument `bar` to be aliased as `x` within the outer function (including any inner functions), as with `jQuery` and `$` in a typical jQuery plugin.

The singleton pattern `var FOO = (function(){ ...; return {...}; })()` forms a namespace `FOO`, with the ability to have private and privileged members.

The pattern `Arc = ( function(window){...} )(window)` is a hybrid of these. `Arc` is `undefined` because the self-executing outer function doesn't return anything. The pattern's utility is therefore equivalent to the first pattern above but with the extra feature of creating the member `Arc`, which consumes a few bytes in the symbol table but is not useful.

Comment: function my_function(){}...does this put my_function in the global namespace...?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on where the statement sits. If it is not localized to an object, array or another function then it will be global. `function my_function(){}` can also be written `var my_function = function(){}`. From this you can see that the rules for function scope are the same as those for variable scope.